# Java Jar running on remote ubuntu server

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, jar, cron

I'm running a service on a remote server using a packaged jar, the problem is when I end the ssh session it also kills the process' including the service I need.

I played with this a year or so ago with a cron script but had no luck, any pointers would be appreciated.

Lewis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) command, this prevent the process from being hung up when the session ends.

```
nohup java -jar myjar.jar
```

Just thought I would add this, in reponse to to what Marvin Pinto said. You can also send the console output to a file like so:

```
nohup java -jar myjar.jar >> logfile.log 2>&1
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the differences but I ended up using `java -jar myjar.jar 2>&1 > log.out &`

Comment: If you don't use "nohup" before the command the process will still be hung up when you end the session even if you have added the '&' to make it run in the background.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use a [screen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen) session for when I need to run similar long-running operations on remote machines.

It becomes easy to join or detach the session whenever I log in or out of the server. The added bonus is that it saves all the stdout/stderr output for when you get back.

Answer (score 3):

Might need more specifics, but in general I think you'll want to look in to nohup or daemonising the process to detach it from the parent shell process.